# Github pages not found (FIle not found) 404

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I'm trying to host my website on github pages here's my repo https://github.com/knoxnethan/knoxnethan.github.io

I'm not sure why I keep getting file not found 404. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6GE1.png)

Comment: Github pages only hosts static files, not web apps. You need to build the react app, then push the resulting `build` folder content to github pages (as in, you'll need a 2nd repo). It'll have an index.html.

Answer (score -1):

There is no homepage in you file index.